# Jordan decomposition of linear functionals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Also, let $C_0(X,\mathbb R)$ denote the vector space of such continuous functions $f:X\to\mathbb R$ that the set $\{x\in X\,|\,|f(x)|\geq\varepsilon\}$ is compact for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Suppose that $I:C_0(X,\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R$ is a bounded, linear functional. Define, for any $f\in C_0(X,[0,\infty))$, $$I^+(f)\equiv\sup\{I(g)\,|\,g\in C_0(X,[0,\infty)),\,0\leq g\leq f\text{ pointwise}\}.$$
The following properties of $I^+$ are known.

- $I^+(f)$ is well-defined (finite) and non-negative for any $f\in C_0(X,[0,\infty))$;
- $I^+(cf)=cI^+(f)$ for any $f\in C_0(X,[0,\infty))$ and $c\geq0$;
- $I^+(f_1+f_2)=I^+(f_1)+I^+(f_2)$ for all $f_1,f_2\in C_0(X,[0,\infty))$.

I am trying to prove the following

**Claim:** If $f\in C_0(X,[0,\infty))$, then it is *impossible* to have *both* $I^+(f)>0$ *and* $I^+(f)>I(f)$. In other words, $I^+(f)\leq\max\{0,I(f)\}$ must hold.

I tried to derive a contradiction using the supremum property, but to no avail so far. Any hint would be appreciated.

---

UPDATE: The claim is **false**, as @ChristianRemling cogently pointed out. FYI, what I ultimately wanted to show is this: If the functionals $I^+$ and $I^-\equiv I^+-I$, which can be meaningfully extended to $C_0(X,\mathbb R)$ from $C_0(X,[0,\infty))$, are given by $I^+(f)=\int f\mathrm d\mu^+$ and $I^-(f)=\int f\mathrm d\mu^-$ $\forall f\in C_0(X,\mathbb R)$ for some finite Radon measures $\mu^+,\mu^-$ on $X$, then $\mu=\mu^+-\mu^-$ is precisely the Jordan decomposition of the signed measure $\mu$. While *this* claim happens to be true, I wanted to prove it using the false claim above in this question. The proof of the claim about the Jordan decomposition of $\mu$ is surprisingly and annoyingly elusive—for those interested, it is proved [here (Proposition 13.42, pp. 279–280)](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/240-01-02/Lecture_Notes/current_versions/chapter13-14.pdf).

Comment: This is false: $I(f)=f(1)-2f(0)$, and consider an $f$ with $f(0)=f(1)=1$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Indeed. Nice counterexample, thank you. If you put it as answer, I will accept it.